# How do I restore the backed up databases?

Tags: 14.04, mysql, backup

I installed a new system of `Ubuntu 14.04.` and `Plesk 12.5`. I backed my previous MySQL-Databases up by saving the `/var/lib/mysql`-folder to another location.

See folder structure

[image]

Now I created empty databases having the same names in Plesk and I moved each database(marked blue) to `/var/lib/mysql`.

The problem is, clicking on the left column in `PHPMySQL`, often times it says that the table doesn't exist and some tables, even though the `frm`-files exist, don't show up.

If I copy the `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile1` and `ib_logfile2` to `/var/lib/mysql`, plesk does not start anymore, showing error messages.

How do I restore the databases?

Comment: It looks like you backed them up in a Windows partition, thus losing all the permissions that they had in the original file system. I'd go with a try and restore them, as they were previously.

Comment: No, everything happened in ubuntu.

Comment: The screen above is from Windows, isn't it? What is the filesystem you backed up them to? NTFS, ext4, btrfs?

Comment: never heard of `mysqldump`? "showing error messages." we need to guess the errors?

Comment: Everything happened in ubuntu, the window is winscp, connected via scp to the ubuntu server. I checked the permissions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wusI2.png

Comment: I understand that the reason for this that plesk also stores it's data in mysql. So I'd have to separate that from the rest. But how.

Comment: @Rinzwind a little late, isn't it?

Comment: @Rinzwind be constructive regarding the status quo

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a virtual machine with virtualbox and ubuntu, creating a mysql-server and moving my files on it. Then I could use mysqldump.

Comment: Oh that is a nice one.

Comment: @Rinzwind so in your long-term experience, you couldn't come up with that? How long was this long-term experience?

Comment: since 2010 or so and no. Mysqldump is the 1st thing you find online when you search on how to backup. Far too dangerous to mess with the files directly so I never bothered with that.